# Grails Referencing Objects in Domain Model

Tags: string, performance, grails, object, dns

I have a simple question, for which I couldn't find answers in the web. Which of the following domain models is more efficient:

```
class Text {

    User author

    static constraints = {}
}

class Text {

    String author

    static constraints = {}
}
```

An user object has the username as a String in it. But which is more efficient? To save the string and search for the object or for saving the object?

Answer (score 0):

The first option would give more accurate results while you would be using criterion query, and it will efficient too, its more easy for JVM to compare object hashcode rather then comparing String while query

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you use an object it tends to make your life easier ahead, especially if your application grows. But if there's not a chance that this app will grow, there's no reason to use an object only with the String author in it (that would be only another level of indirection with no purpose whatsoever). 
For performance, using User is better as it uses [lazy loading](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/lazy.html) by default in one-to-one associations, and the User object will not be loaded when you load the Text object, so you only have User when you ask for it. Besides it's better OOP.
If you're talking about the performance to query authors in these domains, it's the same thing.